# How to calculate the area of a region enclosed by the following curve

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the area of a region enclosed by the following curve?
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^4}{b^4}=1,\quad a,b>0.
$$
[image]
Since the latter term is a power of 4, I wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: How about finding the area only above the x-axis and then extending this result to your 
 problem? You'll need a little algebra to find the expression for $y$ as a function of $x$ and you'll have a few choices to make.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the fact that the curve is symmetric by the horizontal axis (why)? Therefore, we only need to calculate the area of the upper half of the axis (or the region $y \geq 0$) and take $2$ times that result. You can also notice that the curves have endpoints at $x = a$ and $x = -a$, and that the curve had no points that has coordinates beyond them (why?).

Using the area-via-integration formula, we first calculate $y$ based on $x$. Since $y \geq 0$ (we only need to calculate such case), we have:$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^4}{b^4} = 1 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{y^4}{b^4} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2} \\ \Rightarrow y^4 = b^4 \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2} \right) \\ \Rightarrow y = b\sqrt[4]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$$

and for the manipulations I used the fact that $a$ and $b$ are positive.

Here, using the area-by-integration of a function $y = f(x)$ between two endpoints $a$ and $b$, we use the formula: $A = \int_a^b |f(x)|$. Substitute $y$ in, we have $$\text{area}_{y \geq 0} = \int_{-a}^a \left|b \sqrt[4]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}\right| \text{d}x = b \int_{-a}^a \sqrt[4]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \text{d}x$$

and the absolute value signs can be omitted since the intergrand is positive over the entire integrated region, and the constant $b$ can be brought outside the integral. However, I don't know how to evaluate the actual intergrand of $\int_{-a}^a \sqrt[4]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \text{d}x$, so I used WolframAlpha and got the following answer:

[image: answer]

which means $$\text{area}_{y \geq 0} = b\int_{-a}^a \sqrt[4]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \text{d}x = -\frac{\sqrt{2} \pi^{\frac{3}{2}}ab}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left( \frac {7}{4} \right)}$$

and so the final answer would be $$\text{area} = 2 \text{area}_{y \geq 0} = -\frac{2\sqrt{2} \pi^{\frac{3}{2}}ab}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left( \frac {7}{4} \right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: See [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)